# SPSS syntax style for correlation matrix

Tags: syntax, correlation, spss

In the correlation matrix, for each variable, there are 3 rows;

1. correlation value (r)
2. significance value
3. number of cases (n)

I use the style function when producing the matrix to colour the significance value cell yellow. I want to colour the cell above the significance cell yellow if the value in the significance cell is less than 0.05 (or significant).

Usually, the syntax for a correlation matrix that contains the significance value cells is like the following:

```
NONPAR CORR
  /VARIABLES=VASt0movement VAS24hmovement VAS2weeksmovement N_VAS4weeksmovement N_VAS12weeksmovement    
  /PRINT=SPEARMAN TWOTAIL SIG
  /MISSING=PAIRWISE.


OUTPUT MODIFY
  /REPORT PRINTREPORT=NO
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=[LAST] SUBTYPES="Correlations"
  /TABLECELLS SELECT=[SIGNIFICANCE] SELECTDIMENSION=ROWS SELECTCONDITION="x<0.05" 
    BACKGROUNDCOLOR=RGB(255, 255, 0) APPLYTO=CELL.
```